# Django Path Issues - failing to import module on admin screen load

Tags: python, django, shell, path, symlink

I apologize for the abundance of code/config posted - but I'm struggling to find the error and was hoping somebody may be able to spot it. This is my first time working with django/virtualenv so I'm sure it's probably something dumb. For the record, I am using Python 2.7 and Django 1.5. I am on a shared server, but I have a virtual environment with all the necessary dependencies.

Now, I'm able to see the Django welcome screen when my .urls has all the admin pages commented out. However, I've been setting up a sqlite3 (I know it's advised against for production) database to handle my one app, called users.

I can successfully add objects of type User to the database using the python shell. So it's not a database issue. As far as I can tell, as it tries to render the webpage at some point it is calling for the module users, but can't locate it. So, it must be calling from outside the project directory. Which makes me think I need to add something to my path perhaps? But what do i add?

**I have a symlink in my virtualenv site-packages directory to the inner folder of my project - namely project/project (Which is internal of the app *user* ). So my guess is I need to change that symlink to point to the outer project directory instead?**

[image: The root of the error]

---

My project structure is as follows:

```
/project

/project/project_db

/project/manage.py

/project/users/__init__.py

/project/users/admin.py

/project/users/models.py

/project/users/tests.py

/project/users/views.py

/project/project/__init__.py

/project/project/settings.py

/project/project/urls.py

/project/project/wsgi.py
```

---

Now, the relevant files:

/project/project/settings.py

```python
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'project_db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

#...

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'users',
)
```

---

Next:
/project/users/models.py

```python
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):

    CRAWFORD = 'CR'
    CARPENTER = 'CA'
    NOTAPPLICABLE = 'NA'

    HALL_CHOICES = (
        (CRAWFORD, 'Crawford'),
        (CARPENTER, 'Carpenter'),
        (NOTAPPLICABLE, 'Not Applicable'),
    )

    hall = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=HALL_CHOICES,default=NOTAPPLICABLE)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey('self',blank=True, null=True, default=None)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.email + " " + self.hall
```

---

Lastly: .bash_profile

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$HOME/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/bin:$HOME/website/project
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$HOME/website/project
```

Comment: Are you using the built-in Django test server (i.e. `./manage.py runserver`), or something else like apache?

Comment: Hey Aya, I'm on Apache. I never set up a test server (it's a small app). So I've just been developing on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue. Upon reading the tutorial for fastcgi closer - it noted that you may need to add a symlink to the public_html directory for any packages external to the inner project directory. So, since my apps exist within the project but exterior of the inner project directory - fastcgi needs a link to the module in the public_html.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `.bash_profile` you posted is from *your* home directory, and you're running apache in the usual way, i.e. as a daemon process started by user `root` and forking children as user `www-data` or `apache` or somesuch, then the `PYTHONPATH` won't apply to the apache process, so you'll have to configure it separately.

If you're using `mod_wsgi`, then you can add the following apache directive to your webserver config...

```
WSGIPythonPath $HOME/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$HOME/website/project
```

...ensuring you substitute `$HOME` for the full, absolute pathname to your home directory, since it won't be the same for the apache user.

---

**Update**

According to the guide, you should have created a file `~/public_html/dispatch.fcgi`, containing something like...

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.6

import sys
import os

# Make sure to change 'username' to your username!
sys.path.append('/home/username/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproj.settings'

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

...so check you've put the correct paths in the `sys.path.append()` line(s).

Comment: Aya, maybe you missed it in my original post - but I am running on a shared server. I'm using 'a small orange' host, so i've been following these directions https://help.asmallorange.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/140 to get setup (and am using fcgi). I've got through that tutorial with everything working - but then ran into trouble after starting the django tutorial

Comment: @Paul_R Did you create a file `dispatch.fcgi` as the guide suggested, and if so, what are its contents?

Comment: as far as i can tell its contents are fine. If they were incorrect then serving up the html wouldn't be working at all. It can serve up the standard start screen - it only runs into issues when it requires the users module